# C++ fstream, reading data from text and preforming math operations?

Tags: c++, io, fstream, ifstream, file-io

I am at my wits end here. I am writing a program in C++ that will read a text file that contains the following as a brief example:

```
+ 23 34
- 9 8
+ 100 1
* 8 7
^ 2 5
/ 45 8
```

The reader will store the first operands in a char type and based on the char it retrieves, a function will be called to preform the operation on the two numbers, here's a sample functions that will do this.

```
void doDivision(ifstream &inFile) {
    char ch;
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> ch >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Division     " << num1 << "    " << num2 << "    " << "Quotient " << "    " << num1/num2 << " Remain " << num1%num2  << endl; 
}
```

One thing is I am not sure why the argument is &inFile this function prototype is not made by me, but it is from a book maybe this is why I cannot I get it to work.

Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{

ifstream inFile;
char ch;
int num1, num2;

inFile.open("math.txt");
if (inFile.fail())
{
cout << ch;
      cout << "The math.txt input file failed to open";
        return -1;
}


 while(inFile)
{
    switch (ch) {

    case '+':
        doAddition(inFile);
        break;
    case '-':
        doSubtraction(inFile);
        break;
    case '*':
        doMultiplication(inFile);
        cout << "debug " << ch;
        break;
    case '/':
        doDivision(inFile);
        break;
    case '!':
        doFactorial(inFile);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Operation" << endl;

    }

    inFile >> ch;
}

inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

All of this together produces the following unintended result

```
Invalid Operation 
Addition 3 34 sum 37 (wrong data in text file is 23 and 34)
subtraction 0 8 difference 8 (data in textfile is 9 and 8 respectively)
```

How would I implement this, I am overwhelmed since I have never worked with files before.

Comment: assuming you've worked with std::cin, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) is a good reference of std::fstream, which has the same input mechanism as std::cin.

Comment: As with any parsing I have to strongly recommend that you learn to use a proper parser. Try `boost::spirit` for example. To know how to properly parse text is something that is useful in many occasions.

Comment: @AxelOmega i would not use Boost while learning.

Comment: @Aniket: It might be true, but the sooner he gets there the better. My point was that there is a proper way to do this and leraning how to parse files it is something that is good to learn sooner then later. Flex/Bison is of course also an option.

Comment: You should pass file pointer as reference instead of by value to a fn ...here change fn definitions to doAddition(ifstream *fp) and call fn doAddition(&fp)...

Comment: I **highly** recommending searching StackOverflow for these keywords "parsing postfix read file".  I've seen you assignment go by too many times this month.

Comment: @AxelOmega:  The OP's assignment is a postfix / infix / prefix parser.  This is usually assigned as a learning exercise for binary trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple error is that inside of your while() loop, you don't call `inFile >> ch` until after the first time through the loop.  Try fixing that and see if it helps.

Also, what [Aniket said in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15304743/327263) is another problem you need to look out for.

So in short, your loop should look roughly like this:

```
inFile >> ch;
while(inFile) {
    switch(ch) {
    case '+':
        ...
    }
    inFile >> ch;
}
```

And your functions should be similar to this:

```
void doDivision(ifstream &inFile) {
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;

    ...
}
```

Comment: -1: Your first example has a fault. If the input operation fails, it won't be processed until the execution gets to the top of the loop again. In your example, try moving the `inFile >> ch;` to before the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  I've edited my post to take care of that.  Please either let me know again or directly edit it if there's something else I've missed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already doing `inFile >> ch` in `main()` it will be wrong(logically) to read it again in `doAddition()` and other methods.

since you've posted `doDivision()` method where you read in the `ch` character, I am assuming you're doing the same in `doAddition()` as well.

Also your output:

> Addition 3 34 sum 37 (wrong data in text file is 23 and 34)

Tells us all - you've read 1 character(found `+`) then read another character in `doAddition()` method, - which read `2` into `ch` of `doAddition()` then read `3` and `34`..

This is where the error actually is.

Solution: change your `doAddition()` and all other functions to something like below.

```
void doAddition(ifstream &inFile) {
    char ch;
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Addition of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = "<< (num1+num2) << '\n';
}
```

Also, in the `main()` function:

the while loop should look like this:

```
while(inFile)
{
    inFile >> ch;
    switch (ch) {

    case '+':
        doAddition(inFile);
        break;
    case '-':
        doSubtraction(inFile);
        break;
    case '*':
        doMultiplication(inFile);
        cout << "debug " << ch;
        break;
    case '/':
        doDivision(inFile);
        break;
    case '!':
        doFactorial(inFile);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Operation" << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: What about the default case? When an unknown operator is encountered, you'll have **three errors** show up - not one, since `File >> ch` will try to read the next arguments which are **not** operators.

Comment: @jrd1 that's upto OP to decide. He might want to break out of the loop or just report and continue. This is functional issue IMHO.

Comment: Same fault:  the input is not checked after it occurs.  The `inFile >> ch;` will fail at EOF, reading an undefined character and that character is processed through the switch statement.  Leave an input statement at the bottom (there was nothing wrong with it) and also put one before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You do not read into `ch` for the first iteration. In fact, when you check that your file opened with no problem, you do `cout << ch;` despite the fact that `ch` is uninitialized. You could simply move the `inFile >> ch;` to the top of the `while` loop.

The next problem is that inside each of your `doSomething` functions, you are doing `inFile >> ch` again, which will attempt to read the operation character again. Your `doSomething` functions don't need to know `ch` though, since the function itself was chosen based on the value of `ch`.

Here is how I would write this:

```
ifstream inFile("math.txt"); // You can specify the file name here
char op;
int left_operand, right_operand;

// Use extraction has while condition
while (inFile >> op >> left_operand >> right_operand) {
  switch (op) {
    // Pass operands to the relevant function
    case '+': doAddition(left_operand, right_operand); break;
    // ...
  }
}

// You do not need to close inFile, it will be closed when it goes out of scope
return 0;
```

Comment: +1: you beat me to posting (what I'd agree is) the right way to do it by 16 seconds.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, I just saw how similar our solutions were. Eerie!

Comment: One issue with multiple `>>` in the `while` expression is that the fault cannot be isolated to which input.  Also, if the first extraction fails, will the remaining ones be executed?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's true, but if the first one fails, the following will not be executed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, there are **better** ways of doing what you suggest, but if you *have to* make your code look and perform like this, then the appropriate solution should be something of this sort:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void doAddition(ifstream &inFile) {
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Addition of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = "<< (num1+num2) << '\n';   
}

void doSubtraction(ifstream &inFile) {
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Subtraction of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = "<< (num1-num2) << '\n';
}

void doMultiplication(ifstream &inFile) {
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Multiplication of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = "<< (num1*num2) << '\n';
}

void doDivision(ifstream &inFile) {
    float num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "Division of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = "<< (num1/num2) << '\n';
}

void doFactorial(ifstream &inFile) {
    int t1, t2;

    inFile >> t1 >> t2;

    //perform factorial here
}

void readToNextLine(ifstream& inFile) {
    string t1, t2;

    inFile >> t1 >> t2;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    char ch;
    int num1, num2;

    inFile.open("math.txt");

    if (inFile.is_open()){

        inFile >> ch;
        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            switch (ch) 
            {

                case '+':
                    doAddition(inFile);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    doSubtraction(inFile);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    doMultiplication(inFile);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    doDivision(inFile);
                    break;
                case '!':
                    doFactorial(inFile);
                    break;
                default:
                    readToNextLine(inFile);
                    cout << "Invalid Operation" << endl;
            }
            inFile >> ch;
        }
            inFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The math.txt input file failed to open";
        return -1;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

A couple things to note here:

**Some of the solutions that the others suggested, do not consider the default case** - which simply forgoes reading the rest of the line, **resulting in logic errors** - which no one wants.

Now, as for a "better", more general solution, it would be more ideal to store everything as strings first, then tokenize, and attempt to convert the appropriate token to the desired type output.

But, as I noted before, if you wish to conform to the code you had previously, then this is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're feeling masochistic, it's almost certainly easiest to read the operator and two operands all at once, then carry out the operation:

```
char operation;
int operand1, operand2;

while (infile >> op >> operand1 >> operand2) 
   switch(operation) {
       case '+': add(operand1, operand2); break;
       case '-': sub(operand1, operand2); break;
       case '*': mul(operand1, operand2); break;
       case '/': div(operand1, operand2); break;
   }
```

For only four operators, this works well enough as-is. If you're going to have many more, you'd probably be better off using a table of pointers to functions instead:

```
typedef int (*op)(int, int);

op operators[UCHAR_MAX];

for (int i=0; i<UCHAR_MAX; i++)
    operators[i] = report_bad_operator;

operators['+'] = add;
operators['-'] = sub;
operators['/'] = div;
operators['*'] = mul;
// more operators here

while (infile >> operation >> operand1 >> operand2)
    operators[operation](operand1, operand2);
```

The obvious reason/time to do otherwise would be to deal with non-binary operators (i.e., ones that don't necessarily take exactly two operands).

Comment: I'm really curious, if the first `operator` extraction fails, will the other extractions be executed?

Comment: I suggest renaming "operator" variable to something else.  It tends to conflict with the function, such as `operator<()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Once an extraction fails, the failbit for the stream is set, so all further extractions will also fail until the stream is reset. Good point about the name -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are reading chr, before assigning a value to it.

Change your while loop like this:

```
while(inFile)
{
    inFile >> ch; // assign before reading
    switch (ch) {

    case '+':
        doAddition(inFile);
        break;
    case '-':
        doSubtraction(inFile);
        break;
    case '*':
        doMultiplication(inFile);
        cout << "debug " << ch;
        break;
    case '/':
        doDivision(inFile);
        break;
    case '!':
        doFactorial(inFile);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Operation" << endl;
    }
}
```

And change your doDivision function like this:

```
void doDivision(ifstream &inFile)
{ 
    int num1, num2;

    inFile >> num1 >> num2; // your already read the arithmetic operator
    cout << "Division     " << num1 << "    " << num2 << "    " << "Quotient " << " 
}
```

Comment: What about the default case? If the default case is encountered, you'll result in **three errors** being output per line with an unknown operator.

Comment: What happens when `inFile >> ch` in the main loop encounters EOF?  I believe that it has an unknown character (or the last one read) and that is processed through the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, initial pass, your `ch` variable is not initialized.  It *is* initialized at the bottom of the loop.

Try adding:

```
 inFile >> ch;
```

before the while loop.